# Using Try and Catch but can't retry

Tags: java, try-catch

I'm using try-catch to catch and show a retry message, but the error is still there, it just shows the message but don't give us the chance to retry. I don't understand why.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class F_to_Celsius {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(
                "Bonjoir lol \n Convertire de Celsius à Fahrenheit tape 1 \n Convertire de Fahrenheit à Celsius tape 2 ");
        int choix;
        try {
            choix = sc.nextInt();
        } catch (java.util.InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Caractere non numerique § erreur ");
            choix = sc.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("D'accord");
        if (choix != 1 | choix != 2) {
            while (choix != 1 && choix != 2) {
                System.out.println("Reassayez , tapez soit 1 soit 2 !!!!!");
                try {
                    choix = sc.nextInt();
                } catch (java.util.InputMismatchException e) {
                    System.out.println("Caractere non numerique 1 ou 2");
                    choix = sc.nextInt();
                }

            }
        }

        if (choix == 1) {
            System.out.println("Entrez la temperature en Celsius ");
            int tempc = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println(celtofar(tempc) + " F°");
        } else if (choix == 2) {
            System.out.println("Entrez la temperature en Fahrenheit ");
            int tempf = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println(fartocel(tempf) + "C°");
        }
    }

    public static double celtofar(int x) {
        double y = (x * 1.8) + 32;
        return y;

    }

    public static double fartocel(int x) {
        double y = (x - 32) / 1.8;
        return y;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please no images of code and no improper question tags. You'll only get negative attention if you use misleading tags. I've removed the C and the Python tags for you. Note that we cannot copy, paste and run an *image* of code, so you'll need to post the code with your question and make the question more specific.

Comment: okay done but still need help can u light this up for me ?

Comment: Try format your code better pls, so that we can read it and help you out. And pls post the error msg you getting, and perhaps the logic/background of this piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

Dropped your code snippet into IntelliJ and it immediately warned me that your `if (choix != 1 | choix != 2) {` line is always true. Because you're using a bitwise `|` here for two cases in which one will always be true...well, it'll always be true. I think you can just remove that conditional entirely and let the while loop run 0 or more times.